# ScrollTop not working in reactjs when overflow is set to hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a normal react app with some routing, i want to scroll page to top whenever the viewer visits new page via react routing, it is working fine but whenever i set overflow-x to hidden, it stops working

Following is my scrollToTop.js:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function ScrollToTop({ history }) {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    /* eslint-disable */
    const unlisten = history.listen(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });

    return () => {
      unlisten();
    }
  }, []);

  return (null);
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

This is my CSS code:

```
body, html {
  overflow-x: "hidden";
}
```

Please help me, I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) ? It also can scroll page to top.

By the way, in css code should not use double quotes for **"hidden"**.